# Rename the "suggested" tab/filter under Tag Synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, wording

Under the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) section, there's a ["suggested" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) and its tooltip says

> Only suggested synonyms (excluding voted synonyms).

But actually not all suggested synonyms are shown here, only suggested synonyms, not approved yet **on which you are eligible to vote** (i.e. you have enough total answer score in the "master" tag to do it).

I don't know how to name it in one/two words, but I think the tooltip should say something like "Available to vote tag synonyms" instead.

Comment: They also show "pending" on the side which is the other half of those suggested, not confirmed

Comment: @doubleDown, I'm not sure with the language, but as for me, suggested and then approved by community synonym is still suggested. (In opposite to  synonyms __created__ by moderators/devs)

Comment: @RiaD, you mean it still shows under "suggested" even when it has a vote score of 4?

Comment: @doubleDown, no I mean I understand word "suggested" in this way. (I could be wrong, I'll try to investigate it a bit)

Comment: @doubleDown, I hope you don't mind, I edited this part back. [English.SE question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119285/word-suggested-for-already-accepted-proposal)

Comment: No worries. I just think that the term "suggested synonym" would imply that it is either rejected or still under review.